# Copy fonts from windows to linux container through dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function in .NET Core. I am publishing this lambda function as docker image. I need all the windows fonts on the docker container. My docker file is:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:core3.1

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1"  .
COPY "C:/Windows/Fonts/*.ttf"  "/usr/share/fonts"

RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras 
RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
RUN yum install -y libgdiplus  


CMD ["Lambda.PowerPointProcessor::Lambda.PowerPointProcessor.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

When i try publishing the lambda with this docker file, i get the error that

```
C:/Windows/Fonts, no such file or directory
```

How can i copy all the fonts from windows to container ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The image build process has a context directory (in most cases it is the directory the `docker build ...` comannd is run from). We can only `COPY` files that are in this context directory, or its sub-directories.

Comment: That's a lambda function and I believe the docker build of lambda function is handling by AWS publishing mechanism. I am even copying my release build i.e. "COPY "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1"" and it is working fine. @Turing85. Any solution for copying the windows fonts to container?

Comment: As you have just shown, the `COPY` command copies a relative resource that is in the context-directory (hence the relative path). It does not matter whether aws handles the build of the container image; we can only copy from the current context directory. We can - of course - copy all fonts in the context directory before building the image and then reference the "local" fonts in the containerfile.

Comment: Any code or sample docker file for that ? @Turing85